# iOS MapKit - Points per meter

Tags: cocoa, mkmapview, mapkit, core-location

I am drawing a circle in a MKOverlayView subclass. I have a radius in meters. How would I convert said meters to points (at that zoom scale) for drawing in drawMapRect:zoomScale:inContext:?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see headers:

helpers:

```
 // Conversion between distances and projected coordinates
 MK_EXTERN CLLocationDistance MKMetersPerMapPointAtLatitude(CLLocationDegrees latitude) NS_AVAILABLE(NA, 4_0);
 MK_EXTERN double MKMapPointsPerMeterAtLatitude(CLLocationDegrees latitude) NS_AVAILABLE(NA, 4_0);

 MK_EXTERN CLLocationDistance MKMetersBetweenMapPoints(MKMapPoint a, MKMapPoint b) NS_AVAILABLE(NA, 4_0);
```

and from the MKOverlayView

```
 // Convert screen points relative to this view to absolute MKMapPoints
 - (CGPoint)pointForMapPoint:(MKMapPoint)mapPoint;
 - (MKMapPoint)mapPointForPoint:(CGPoint)point;
```

so

```
double ppm = MKMapPointsPerMeterAtLatitude(centerCoordinate.latitude);
MKMapPoint mkptLeftmost = ptCenter.x -= ppm;
CGPoint ptLeftmost  = [self pointForMapPoint:mkptLeftmost];
```

Comment: typed inline - no guarantees ... but thats the approach

Comment: I'll accept this because it's an okay answer. The issues I thought I was experiencing was unrelated.